# Recieving 403.4 Error only from a specific server & on speficic files

Tags: iis-6, http-status-code-403

I have a wierd problem, I've launched a website recently on IIS6, and it is working good, accesible from every computer I've tested. On one network, however, the one's of my client, it is only partially accesible.

When trying to reach the web site on any of their computers, they recieve a **403.4 Error**:

```
HTTP 403.4 - Forbidden: SSL is required to view this resource
```

**They recieve this error only when entering the address without "www"**. When entering "www.domain.com" it is being loaded fine.

From what I've read, it can be fixed by changing a setting '*Require Secure Channel (SSL)*', however it is not checked, not as a website configuration and not in the files configurations.

What could be the problem, either on the website configuration or the network?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you have more than one website defined, and they have different and specific host headers defined (do you have any host headers defined on any of the websites? If so, if the client's typing one that doesn't match, it'll fall through to any site with a generic port binding and no host header). Or a crazy rewrite rule. Or a bad proxy.